# If $\limsup_{n} P^n(x,C) \le 1-\epsilon$ then the average of the transition probabilities cannot be tight.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Assume that there exists some $\epsilon>0$  such that for every compact $C$ we have 
$$\limsup_{n} P^n(x,C) \le 1-\epsilon.$$
Then why does this imply that the sequence $\{ \bar{P_k}(x,\cdot):k\in \mathbb{N} \}$ is not tight, where we define 
$$\bar{P_k}(x,\cdot):= \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k P^i(x,\cdot).$$

Tight here means that for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists a compact set $C$ such that $\liminf_{k\to \infty} \bar{P_k}(x,C) \ge 1-\epsilon$.

I think this uses the idea that we have for sufficiently large $n \ge N$, $P^n(x,C)\le 1-\epsilon /2$. And if the average of $P^i(x,\cdot)$ is tight, then we must have 
$$\liminf_k \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k P^i(x,C) \ge 1-\epsilon/4$$ which implies that for some $i$, we must have $P^i(x,C) \ge 1-\epsilon/4$.

However, I cannot guarantee that this $i$ must be $\ge N$, to derive a contrdiction. I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $\limsup_{n} P^n(x,C) \le 1-\epsilon$ implies that for some $N$, one has $P^n(x,C) \le 1-\epsilon<1-\epsilon/2$ for all $n\ge N$, as you have already observed. Now for $k\geq N$, we have $$\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k P^i(x,C)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} P^i(x,C)+\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=N}^{k} P^i(x,C)\le\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} P^i(x,C)+\frac{k-N+1}{k}(1-\epsilon/2).$$ Since $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} P^i(x,C)=0,$$
and $$\frac{k-N+1}{k}(1-\epsilon/2)\leq (1-\epsilon/2)$$
for all $k\geq N$
we get $$\limsup_k \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k P^i(x,C) \leq 1-\epsilon/2,$$
and *a fortiori* also 
$$\liminf_k \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k P^i(x,C) \leq 1-\epsilon/2.$$